# How do I make a custom vertical slider that sits alongside text?

Tags: ios, swift

[I want to make a custom scrollviewindicator like this slider that doesn't disappear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1q3D.png)

What is the best way to do this in Swift 4?

I'm still at level noob. So far I have a textview within a scrollView. I have turned off the default horizontal and vertical scrolls, and added padding around text with UIEdgeInsets.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you can use a `UISlider` vertically placed right next to the scrollview, and when the values for `UISlider` are changed, you can change offset for your `UIScrollview` thus scrolling it.

Comment: You could use a UISlider like Shama says. Personally, I would use a UIProgressView because it was made for these reasons specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need set some constraints after the rotation, but other than that, I think this will work. I would try the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider! {
    didSet {
        configureSlider()
    }
}

//Actually rotates the slider
func configureSlider() {
    slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
// Probably add some constraints here
}

// Create an action, and make sure the sender is a UISlider so you have access to the .value property
@IBAction func valueDidChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let contentSize = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let yPosition = contentSize * CGFloat(sender.value)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPosition), animated: true)
}
```

Give that a try. Best wishes!